# Can superficial injury and exercise elevate AST and LDH levels?

Tags: blood-tests, statistics, liver

Reading the information available [here](http://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/aspartate-aminotransferase-ast#1) and [here](https://www.melanoma.org/find-support/patient-community/mpip-melanoma-patients-information-page/ldh-levels-1int), it's stated that both exercise and other injuries can cause elevated results on a couple of indicators commonly used to measure liver function.  Specifically, it's noted that:

> High levels of AST may be caused by:
>
> - [...]
> - Very strenuous exercise or severe injury to a muscle.

...and:

> Some of the elevated LDH level causes include **tissue damage due to
>   trauma** or disease, a recent heart attack, disease of the liver or the
>   kidney or even the lungs, cancer, anemia, HIV, meningitis or
>   encephalitis to name a few.

Which are fairly consistent but also a bit vague.

For instance, how strenuous must the exercise be to trigger a detectable increase?  Are we talking about something on the order of running a marathon, or more like pushing things a bit too hard at the gym?  And when it comes to injury/trauma, would superficial injuries like cuts, scrapes, and bruises be expected to have an effect, or must it be something more severe like a heart attack or other major internal injury?  Lastly, what magnitude of increase would typically be attributable to "strenuous exercise or severe injury"?

Answer (score 6):

Right now I can address the question on intensity, it seems that pushing things a bit too hard at the gym can cause elevated levels to trigger a detectable increase in AST and LDH, this is also dependent on how "fit" you are as well.

> Exercise is known to contribute to increased levels of potassium,
> urea, creatinine, creatine kinase, lactate dehydrogenase (LDH),
> aspartate aminotransferase (AST), alkaline phosphatase, bilirubin,
> uric acid, as well as the white blood cell count. The amount of
> increase depends on several factors, including duration and intensity
> of exercise and the patient’s fitness level. One thing is clear: the
> less fit you are, the more vigorous and prolonged exercise may affect
> your results.

Source: https://www.biron.com/en/education-center/specialist-advice/impact-exercise/creatine-kinase/

Paper: **Muscular exercise can cause highly pathological liver function tests in healthy men**

> Weightlifting results in profound increases in liver function tests in
> healthy men used to moderate physical activity, not including
> weightlifting. Liver function tests are significantly increased for at
> least 7 days after weightlifting. It is important to impose relevant
> restrictions on heavy muscular exercise prior to and during clinical
> studies.

Source: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17764474/

Paper: **Elevated liver enzymes following polytraumatic injury**

> Currently I am not able to find any solid research if superficial injuries such as scrapes,
> cuts, or bruises cause elevated liver enzymes. However Traumatic Brain Injuries(TBI) and
> Polytraumatic injuries, traumatic injuries that affect two or more body systems or organs, along
> with traumatic amputations, severe burns, orthopedic trauma and or damage to internal organs
> can cause liver enzymes to be elevated.

Source: [https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25479083/#:~:text=Regardless%20of%20demographics%2C%20mechanism%20of%20injury%2C%20or%20extent,most%20cases%2C%20no%20specific%20etiology%20was%20ever%20defined](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25479083/#:%7E:text=Regardless%20of%20demographics%2C%20mechanism%20of%20injury%2C%20or%20extent,most%20cases%2C%20no%20specific%20etiology%20was%20ever%20defined).

Comment: We need answers based on reputable sources, not personal anecdote.

Comment: Understood, there are many research papers on this specific topic a google search away. I will make sure to edit my answer, remove the personal anecdote, and post the appropriate research paper.

Comment: Excellent; once you've done so, you can flag your answer as "in need of moderator intervention" so we are aware and can remove the post notice.

Comment: Can my answer be improved?

Comment: Well, you answered the part about exercise but not about superficial injuries. Addressing both would improve your answer.

Comment: Got it. Found some more interesting research on that question.

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to the site :)

Comment: Thank you :) @Narusan